# Headwind issues

Tags: commuter, wind

I commute  to school (11-12 km one-way) pretty early in the morning (6:30 Indian Standard Time). I live near the coast and the headwinds that I face on the way to school are pretty brutal. They reduce my hard-earned speed and screw up my cadence, hence making me pretty exhausted by the time I reach school. Are there any tips that you can give me to reduce the effect of headwinds? (I also carry a backpack)(I ride a flatbar with 1.75 inch (44.5 mm) wide tires)

Comment: It is common cycling knowledge that as a cyclist you always have the wind in the face. But that put aside the only thing to do is to tuck in as much as possible to have the smallest possible frontal surface.

Comment: @gerrit: 1.75 tyres meaning the tyre width is 1.75 inches or 1 3/4 inches.

Comment: @Carel I see, thanks (quite wide tires).  I have edited that into the question.

Comment: It is good training!

Comment: Just ride a little slower. It really helps a lot.

Comment: Do you have access to bar-ends?  One chap here at work rides his MTB with full aerobars, claims to be 8-10% faster on average, on the open parts (bad in traffic/close areas because of distance between hands and brake levers)

Comment: Related [What's more aerodynamic on flat bars: backpack or pannier?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/45205/7309) (asked by me a few years ago).

Comment: Is it an option for you to move? If you live near the coast and the school is away from the coast inside the land, you are cycling against the sea breeze in both directions. Since you can't change the business hours, you may be able to change your commute direction.

Comment: Recumbent bike? Go slower? Different route? What sort of options do you have?

Comment: @cooper.hat. I'm currently not owning a recumbent bike. There is an alternate route, but it is 1 km longer and it involves staying on the coastal road for longer

Comment: Could you give us some numbers on your speed (ideally average or target moving speed) and typical  wind speeds? I'd like to run the numbers through http://bikecalculator.com/

Answer (score 14):

Take it easy and shift to an easier gear. It sounds like your main problem is not the reduced speed but exhaustion. The good thing with headwinds (unlike hills) is that most bikes have low enough gears available to make pedaling against it easy.

Aerodynamics is mostly affected by frontal area and shape. Close fitting clothes (and backpack), low and narrow handlebars and narrower tires can help.

Of course there are also bicycles and especially wheels which are made to be as aerodynamic as possible. Time trial bikes, (“racing”) recumbents and velomobiles are the most extreme forms, but there are also road bikes which are optimized for aerodynamics. Usually all of these are quite expensive though.

Answer (score 11):

When your biggest problem is a headwind, being more aerodynamic helps.  In a severe headwind, it becomes more important than many other considerations.

I posted a link in the comments to [GCN's commuting aero challenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdfB5fbVHck).  This shows that panniers are bad into the wind, backpacks much better, and a bikepacking saddlebag better still.  Yes they went fast, 40 km/h, but if you try to ride at 25km/h into a 25km/h headwind the power lost to drag is about the same. There are a few more conclusions we can draw either directly from the video or after watching it (including the discussion at the end).

- A backpack isn't bad in its own right, but is worse the more aero (lower) you get, as it's exposed to more wind.
- Look at his clothing - it's skin-tight and fairly smooth, good for aerodynamics.  A baggy shirt is the opposite, and a half-unzipped jacket might as well be a parachute.  This may be the easiest area to improve.  I'm not telling you to wear a skinsuit or even lycra, but to choose an outfit that flaps less on windy days.
- Getting low is good - you might be able to fit clip-on aero bars, even if you've got flat bars.  They have their downside though - for commuting the biggest is probably that your hands are a long way from the brakes.
- I trimmed the handlebars down on one of my bikes.  50mm narrower (25mm off each end) probably didn't make much difference to my frontal area, and I also changed my tyres to reduce rolling resistance, but I was quicker.

I've ridden into horrible headwinds with panniers and with backpacks. I'm no fan of riding with a backpack, but when fighting the wind for every bit of forward movement, they're preferable to panniers.

In addition to being more aero:

- More efficient tyres will help with the overall effort (lower rolling resistance, which probably means less tread and may mean narrower) as will thinking carefully about what accessories you're carrying and where.
- Saving weight helps if you're climbing or frequently stopping and starting, but not really on a steady flat ride, unless it brings bulk with it.  So consider what you carry, and if you're replacing tyres, you should be able to save a little there.

Comment: Actually, front panniers have been shown to be beneficial.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I couldn't find a similar comparison, but the one I recall has them a bit better than rear panniers, which could still make them worse than the alternatives. And that's in a pure headwind. If the wind shifts to the side they're hard work. But the main reason I didn't include them is that they're uncommon, as are the mounting points for a front rack.

Comment: From your GCN video, the difference in power needed between panniers and backpack is laughable:
https://i.ibb.co/cFJ6Vsz/groundbreaking.png (unfortunately there is no scale)
I estimate the average power applied by a ciclist on the order of 80-100W ... so the difference is on the order of 2-3% at most.

Comment: @EarlGrey it's easier to see the force numbers in the video; the difference in drag is then about 10%.  The video is also for a rider in a fairly aero position on a road bike; on flat bars sitting up the backpack will be lower drag and the panniers unchanged.

Comment: ...@EarlGrey some more videos in [an answer to my old question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/45207/7309).  I failed to find them when I wrote the answer

Comment: @ChrisH I understand, however drag is marginal, 10% increase of the 10% of the power loss due to drag is 1%, in the total power output.
My point is: we are not talking about racing cars, not even racing cyclists, where the objective power and consumption theoretically may be calculated. We are talking about a human pedaling his way: the individual factors are much relevant. Over 11km distance, even 1km in discomfort and reduced output because the backpack is sticking to a sweaty back is probably decreasing the "performance" of the biological system of >>1% over the course of the total trip.

Comment: @EarlGrey why do you say 10% of power is lost to drag? It dominates rolling resistance over about 12km/h (see [figure 2 here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rinard/aero/formulas.html)).  By 25km/h nearly 90%  of your work goes into overcoming drag, and that's in still air.  *Drag isn't marginal*

Comment: @ChrisH I say so exactly because of the fig.2 reference you mention
"In normal riding, a bicycle cannot proceed at a constant speed. [...] Kyle calculated the energy to overcome the individual retarding forces for a trip on a touring bike assuming a constant power input of 187 W - this corresponds to a speed of 32 km/h [...] Under these conditions 53% of the energy goes into air resistance [...] 36% into acceleration work."
And he is discussing a speed of 32 km/h ... given the square/cubic dependence of drag, going at half that speed... air resistance is further reduced

Comment: @EarlGrey 53% is very different from your 10%, and that's even with a stop every 400m (hidden by your ellipses).  The 32km/h is the steady state *equivalent* speed for the input power of 187W.  In other words if you work as hard as would propel you at a constant 32 km/h but have to stop every 1/4 mile, you *still* spend over half your effort on drag.  Your own quote demonstrates that drag is far from marginal, and that's all I have to say on the matter. (I'm not keen on sweaty backpacks myself BTW)

Comment: I disagree with the blanket statement that panniers are worse than a backpack. The backpack influences how you sit on your bike and move, which has a fully different impact on the actual speed and exhaustion than panniers. (But an 'on a rack' back or other frame supported carry option is likely better than panniers.)

Comment: @Willeke worse from an aerodynamic perspective; unless you get very low or have a very tall backpack it won't increase your cross section. Ergonomics may be different, but a headwind makes aerodynamics a bigger issue than otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisH Air resistance is proportional to the cube of speed.
Acceleration to the square of the speed.
If you then look at the initial plot your video gave, which is that panniers make your effort a couple of watt more than with the backpack, purely because of air drag, you understand that those couple of watts are negligible.
The air drag is and will always be there. You can change some percentage of it, at best 10%, of something that accounts for 53% if you put as much effort as you would going at 32 km/h (which I consider an enormous effort for the median commuter by bicycle).

Comment: Huh? Acceleration is the derivative of speed, how can it also be proportional to the square of speed? And where are you getting this air resistance proportional to the cube of speed? I thought it was 1/2 * air density * velocity^2 * coefficient of drag * frontal area?

Comment: @PhilFrost  1/2 * air density * velocity^2 * coefficient of drag * frontal area = airDrag.
To travel a certain distance d in a certain time t, you then spend airDrag * d energy.
Since you spent it over a certain time t, you need a power (airDrag * d) /t .
Which is airDrag * velocity, proportional to v^3 .
To accelerate to a certain speed v, you need only to apply a certain force m*a until you reach that speed. Same manipulation, you can show you need a power proportional to v^2  Forgot to mention the proportion of differetn terms wrt the power.

Comment: Are wind speed and ground speed equal _when riding in a headwind_? Not sure about power to accelerate: F=ma, multiply by velocity (once) to get power. Where would a second velocity term come from to square it? Maybe the confusion is with the v^2 term in kinetic energy? Isn't the power required to accelerate to some speed (in an otherwise friction-less environment) also a function of _how long_ some power can be applied, and not simply proportional to the square of velocity?

Comment: @EarlGrey careful with your velocities in a headwind. The first velocity, that gets squared, is your airspeed; the second in the power calculation, is your groundspeed, so power is *not* proportional to any single velocity, but to (V_air^2)*(V_ground).  In still air they're the same of course, and that's why your 53% is a lower bound for the 187W input power - that's still air.

Comment: As for the acceleration: the instantaneous power due only to acceleration is P=Fv = mav  =mv (dv/dt).  Integrate w.r.t time and you'll see it takes a fixed amount of energy to accelerate to a the same final speed whether you accelerate hard or gently - recalling that this is in the absence of losses. So the power (now averaged over the ride) lost to stop-start riding depends mainly on the *number* of stops.  We lack information from the OP about that, so I considered that to be a minor point in the answer.  (Also @PhilFrost)

Comment: @ChrisH good points.
 airDrag * velocity = (some coefficient) * (v_wind + v_ground)^2 * v_ground
There is a cube dependency on v_ground, to be compared with the square dependency, but there is also a term v_wind*v_ground which may be overwhelming (I am rushing to catch a train, a rapid evaluation can be done according to your graduation date paper-pencil plot (80s and before) excel file (90s) matlab (00s) Python (10s). Many R-C++-Octave-WolframAlpha lovers have been hurted writing this comment.

Comment: @EarlGrey it depends which graduation, but before Python it would have been VB, and before that Pascal.  The 25km/h groundspeed + 25km/h headwind calculation was done in LibreOffice though.  By your assessment I'm therefore going back in time, but I'm not getting any younger.  Maybe I'm just getting blown backwards.

Comment: @ChrisH *25km/h headwind*  If that's the offical wind speed, that's measured 10m above ground.  Actual ground-level wind speed will be lower.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it's an example I plucked out of thin air to make the numbers work with a reasonable commuting speed

Answer (score 10):

One thing to understand is that wind resistance is roughly a function of relative wind speed *squared*.  That is, if your speed, relative to the wind, increases from 10mph to 15mph, the "drag" from wind resistance doesn't simply increase by 50%, it increases by about 120%.  So your effort level, due to wind resistance, will more than double.  (On the other hand, per-mile energy loss due to rolling resistance doesn't change much with speed.)

One thing you can do is consider the route.  On a morning when the headwind is bad it may be better to take a slightly longer route which is more sheltered by trees, etc.

Comment: Probably better to point out that the power output required to overcome drag due to wind resistance varies with the *cube* of the rider's velocity relative to the air.

Comment: @PaulH The aerodynamic drag force is proportional to the square of velocity. Force times velocity equals power. So the power to overcome drag is proportional to the cube of velocity _only if wind speed equals ground speed_, which is does not in this question about headwinds. Power to overcome drag is proportional to the wind speed squared, times the ground speed.

Comment: @PhilFrost the operative statement in my comment was "rider's velocity *relative to the air*"

Comment: @PaulH Yes I did read that, but it's incorrect. Power to overcome drag is proportional to the velocity relative to the air *squared* times the velocity relative to the ground. If the wind isn't blowing then these two velocities are equal and it simplifies to just "velocity (relative to air, or ground, doesn't matter because they are equal) cubed", but this question is about a headwind so the velocities are not equal, so the simplification can't be made.

Comment: @PhilFrost While a direct simplification can't be made because power won't be directly proportional to the third power of velocity with a headwind, the marginal change in power required to increase velocity is stil largely proportional to the cube of velocity: `P = Cda * Vg * ( Vg + Vw )^2` => `P = Cda * (Vg^3 + 2Vg^2 * Vw + Vg * Vw^2)`.  And note that offical wind speed is measured at 10m above ground - actual wind speed near the ground will be lower. So the cube of the velocity over ground will dominate sooner than expected if you use the "official" wind speed.

Comment: I think anyone using wind speed at 10 meters above ground for calculating cycling dynamics has issues beyond what's being discussed here.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from improving efficiency (well covered in other answers), which quickly gets into marginal gains without spending big money, it helps to also tackle this from a phycological point of view - Think about time, not distance. "Today is going to be a 30minute ride, yesterday was a 45 minute ride". A head wind means more work, but if you give yourself the time and permission to ride slower, no need to arrive exhausted.

Effort (measure though a heart rate monitor if you can) and cadence are the two things you can control.  Dial in an effort and cadence that is comfortable, so that you arrive without being exhausted, and accept the speed. Obviously if your going slower it will take longer, so factor this it when working out the effort you need.

The distance is not huge, as you get more cycle fit and used to riding, the commute will become easier.  In the mean time, if can afford it, an electric assisted bike would make the problem disappear and could be worth considering.

Comment: Very true. Since I’ve got a power meter I hate headwinds much less. I just shift to an easier gear, ride the power I’d ride anyway and don’t care about the 2 or 3km/h (or even 10km/h) lower speed.

Answer (score 4):

Not really sure this is too feasible as some of the comments have said, the wind is always against a cyclist. However, what I'd do:

- Consider narrower tyres (though the relationship between tyre width and speed is [not linear](https://www.cyclist.co.uk/in-depth/8131/can-wider-tyres-and-lower-pressures-make-you-faster), something like 38mm or 40mm might help you a "very small" amount from the 1.75" you're at right now while preserving balance);
- Consider a rack for the backpack to move the luggage lower down (though this doesn't help with the aerodynamics, as pointed out in the comments, it might still feel easier/lighter);
- Consider a more aerodynamic helmet though the effects are likely to be minimal;
- Consider altering your posture to bring your body lower down;
- Consider a route that might be longer but work with the wind for a bit of time (but not knowing the specific area I'm not sure that's possible—but if you could loop around inland and then use the wind to get to the school, this could be your best bet);
- Consider the time you're heading out as many coastal locations have relatively regular time-dependency on whether the wind is from the sea or from the land (again, I'm not sure if this is feasible for you).

It might be that the condition of your local roads makes some or all of the above very difficult to achieve, so it's hard to say how useful any of these are.

Comment: The contribution of tire width to wind resistance is laughably small.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Yes, sorry, I wasn't suggesting narrower tyres for lower wind resistance but rather to increase speed. As I noted above, the effects are minimal and possibly more psychological than real (though if the OP 'feels' they are going faster that will also be a benefit).

Comment: See the [GCN Commute Aero Challange](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdfB5fbVHck).  Panniers (or I would assume a backpack on a rack) are *less* aero than wearing a backpack; bikepacking luggage is best though expensive and  hard/slow to pack.

Comment: Make sure the tyres are pumped up to close to maximum pressure in an attempt to reduce rolling resistance. Narrower/smoother tyres would help [if feasible and depending on local conditions].

Comment: @ChrisH, bike packing luggage can only be best if the pack does not influence the cyclist at all. Cycling in a windy environment all my life I do not agree that having a backpack on a longer (or harder) ride works. Packing it on your bike behind you, like on a rack, feels much easier.

Comment: @Willeke I have huge same saddlebag they use in the video. I don't notice it's there until I lift the bike, even with several kg in it. That's the point. My panniers affect me more - when not clipped in I have to be careful not to kick them. The panniers are also worse in a crosswind

Comment: @gktscrk I'll approve it on desktop (I don't use the app). Not sure about more professional though - maybe more stubborn at plodding on.

Comment: @JeremyBoden Maximum pressure is great if you're on smooth, high-quality surfaces. If the surface is rough, dropping the pressure a bit may be better.

Answer (score 3):

At the speed you can achieve, the panniers or at least a rack and a box to hold your backpack will help you not straining your back and your core muscles, while at the same time not affecting too much your aerodynamics, leaving you less exhausted. Your back is squeezed in between the weight of the backpack and resisting the push of the wind.

Everytime a gust of wind arrives, the muscles have to react to the gust, to keep you in balance, when the gust fades out the muscles have to counterbalance the backpack. Repeat this over 11kms. Not good at all.

I would suggest improve your comfort, not your speed, so buy a rack and possibly a foldable box to hold your backpack when needed:

[image: I suggest looking for "folding basket bike" in your preferred search engine]

I suggest looking for "folding basket bike" in your preferred search engine.

As the video of the other answer shows (GCN aerodynamics) the backpack vs panniers gain in terms of power are on the order of 1-5 W ... negligible, unless you are racing and that few %s is the difference between winning and loosing.

Comment: As an alternative, using bungies to secure the pack on top of the rack will work.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibilities I completely forgot, but that I used when living in the Netherlands (a country were apparently it does not matter which direction you go, you always have headwind) is using tri-bar extensions.

You may know them because they are used in this set-up:
[image]

but they are actually attached to the handlebar of any bike, in the Netherlands the closer you are to the seaside (Delft and other cities/towns) the more you could see bicycles with these contraptions on the handlebar

An extreme (and overblown, given the racing wheels) example is this one:

[image]

But something less extreme was not uncommon to be seen. If you have quiet stretches, where you can safely keep your hands away from the brakes (which means not much traffic, no pedestrians, smooth pavement, etcetc), you may find some cheap aero-bar or tri-bar in the usual internet stores.

Comment: +1 for always facing headwinds in the Netherlands.